# Is it possible to use async/await when invoking a method specified by an inteface?

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
    export interface UserAuthenticator
    {
        async isValid(username: string, password: string): Promise<boolean>
    }
```

Compiling generates error message `TS1070: 'async' modifier cannot appear on a type member.`

Comment: There is no rason to mark the method as async that is a modifier for the implementation. The fact that the method returns a promise will make it awaitable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async` keyword is used on the implementation of the method. It doesn't have any meaning on the interface itself. One implementation of the interface could use async/await in its implementation, and another could just return a Promise without the use of await. Theoretically both styles of implementation could have the same behavior and would both conform to the interface.